# Ошибка Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: javascript, gulp, version, autoprefixer

Когда подключаю gulp-autoprefixer или другие ... может возникнуть такая ошибка, она решается путем скачивание этого же плагина, но версией меньше, есть способ, который позволяет не скачивать версию меньше? Может эти функции уже убрали в новых версиях или почему ошибка?

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const scss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

function styles() {
  return src('app/scss/style.scss')
  .pipe(scss({outputStyle:'compressed'}))
  .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
  .pipe(autoprefixer({
    cascade: false
  }))
  .pipe(dest('app/css'))
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также версии плагинов:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`gulp-autoprefixer` импортируемый вами пакет был преобразован в пакет только для ESM, а это означает, что пакет больше нельзя импортировать с помощью `require()`.

[См. доку](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#:%7E:text=ECMAScript%20modules%20are%20the%20official,%3B%20%7D%20export%20%7B%20addTwo%20%7D%3B%20copy)